# Get unique IDs for multiple INSERT

Tags: mysql

I need to get back all the inserted IDs (from an auto-incremented field) from a single query that inserts something like 20+ rows into a MySQL database. I've got something like this so far:

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] ( ... ) VALUES ( ... ), ( ... ), ( ... );
```

How would I need to modify the above query to get back all inserted IDs?

I've found a few topics where the use of DECLARE was suggested, but PhpMyAdmin always returned an error, when I tried to run the query.

Thanks!

Comment: With the above query I can get the first inserted ID back plus the number of rows affected, so I could just calculate the IDs that way, but the question then is if the result is correct. Do queries in MySQL get chained or can they happen parallel?

Comment: My database is of the type MyISAM. Just read somewhere that queries for that type cannot happen simultaniously, so I should be alright calculating the IDs based on the first ID and the affected rows, right?

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM should be locking the table for your insert, so it feels like you'd be OK getting one value back and offsetting with the number of rows affected.

To be really safe, how about adding a 'batch' column and inserting a session-based variable?  Then you could select out the IDs that had that value.  Not great, but...